# Django 1.11 Python 3.6 ImageField 404 Error

Tags: django, imagefield

[image]

Not sure how to display my ImageField in Django. Currently, my images are located in /media/static/ and the paths on my terminal all match up to where the images are locally. How come the images do not display?

[image: index.html]

^^ using above code in index.html to display the image.

[image]

^^ settings.py

[image]

^^ urls.py within the current application

[image]

^^ models.py

[image]

^^ views.py

Comment: you need to post more codes, like the view the model and the full html

Comment: Please don't post screenshots next time but paste code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add `MEDIA_URL` to your urlpatterns(see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)):

```
urlpatterns = [
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I see. I read that I had to add to urlpatterns in the docs. Turns out two mistakes:

1) I used STATIC_URL, and STATIC_ROOT to add to urlpatterns instead of MEDIA_URL, and MEDIA_ROOT

2) I added to urlpatterns in the urls.py of my app and not my project. 

I still need to spend more time on the docs to understand why that is. 

Thanks @neverwalkaloner!